# a driver for an integrated video card for amd radeon r4 video adapter

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics

I need a driver for an integrated video card for amd radeon r4 video adapter in a6 9220e processor. The driver is needed for debian (ubuntu). I bought an aser aspire xc-330 (dt.bcse.004) computer and an HP 19ka monitor. Where can i find a suitable driver?